# WebSphere 6.1: can not start admin console after SSL-cert installation

Tags: ssl, websphere, ibm-rad, ibm-rational

I installed a self-signed certificate and restartet. Now i can't start the admin console any more. I am really new to websphere, and must have some errors when installing the certificate.

When I connect to https://localhost:9043/ibm/console I get the following error in firefox: 
 ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap

and the following exception in the console:  [21.07.09 09:58:25:583 CEST] 00000020 SSLHandshakeE E   SSLC0008E: Die SSL-Verbindung kann nicht initialisiert werden. Es wurde ein unbefugter Zugriff verweigert, oder die Sicherheitseinstellungen sind verfallen. Die Ausnahme ist javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Client requested protocol SSLv3 not enabled or not supported.

Is there a way to get into the admin console to fix this? Withour reconfiguring the whole server? Im running RationalApplicationDeveloper 7.0 and WebSphere 6.1.

Thanks

**Update**: Screenshot added:

IE6 says: "Fehler: Server oder DNS kann nicht gefunden werden" ~= "DNS not found"

[alt text http://web2.twitpic.com/img/18628664-5b415b1aba308587a47589893e0cb0b7.4a657676-scaled.jpg](http://web2.twitpic.com/img/18628664-5b415b1aba308587a47589893e0cb0b7.4a657676-scaled.jpg)

Comment: For development purposes you shouldn't bother with ssl. Try accessing the console with other browsers? What do they say? A screenshot pls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(from memory)..

locate security.xml for your 'profile' (in the /runtimes/base_v6/profiles/AppServer/config/cells//security.xml) 
and locate the root tag "security:Security" and set the attribute "enabled" to "false".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<security:Security xmi:version="2.0" (.....)  enabled="false" (....)>
```

Comment: alterantive: disable security using console application "wsadmin" http://letmehelpyougeeks.blogspot.com/2009/02/disabling-administrative-security-in.html

Answer (score 1):

This particular fix didn't work for me (Websphere 6.1 on windows 2008). However, it appears the system keeps previous versions of the security.xml file. Grabbing the most recent copy available and replacing the now failing one did the trick for me and the console was accesible again.

Comment: where did you find the older copy of security.xml?